# Visual Studio Ctrl+ Comma equivalent in Intellij

Tags: java, visual-studio, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to find that Navigate To command just like in Visual Studio.

In VS 2013 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>(Comma) opens a search bar and then it searches the related objects properties classes all the related stuff and when you press enter it will navigate you easily.

What is the equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>(Comma) in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found out that **double pressing** <kbd>↑</kbd>**(Shift)** button has the pretty much same command for IntelliJ